# Arcade Expression for radio button in ArcGIS Field Maps

Tags: arcade, forms, arcgis-field-maps

I'm trying to set a field in a pop up that appears when a feature is clicked. The attributes show up in the pop up and then one must hit the edit icon which brings the form view for the feature up on the left side of map viewer.

One of the editable fields is called "Inspected" and is a switch value where the default is "No" (off setting) and "Yes" would be the value chosen once a feature is inspected int he field.

If the "Inspected" field switch is turned on, changing the value to yes, I would like another field called "DATE_INSPECTED" to auto populate with the the current date.

I tried this expression:

```
var inspection_date = $feature.DATE_INSPECTED;
var inspected = $feature.INSPECTED;

if(inspected == 'Yes'){
  inspection_date = Today();
};
```

But nothing happens. Also I get a message after writing the expression under the "Editable" check box: Form element has calculated expression. Ensure editing is disabled.

Why would you have switch button to toggle between values if the user couldn't change it? Is this what's causing the problem? Do I need to put the expression in a function?